# Error when file loading

Tags: actionscript-3, file, uploading

I have a button and progressbar on stage. I tried to load an image in the same folder of  the flash but it didn't work. I get the following errors:

> 1119: Access of possibly undefined property contentLoaderInfo through
>   a reference with static type flash.net:URLLoader.

And:

> 1067: Implicit coercion of a value of type flash.net:URLLoader to an unrelated type flash.display:DisplayObject.

Here's my code:

```
import flash.net.URLLoader;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

var myLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();

btn_Img.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, uploadPic);

function uploadPic(event:MouseEvent):void{
   myPb.source = myLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, imageLoad);
     myLoader.load(new URLRequest("myImage.png"));
    btn_Img = null;
        addChild(myPb);
        removeChild(myPb);
}


function imageLoad(event:Event):void{
        addChild(myLoader);
    btn_Img = null;
}
```

Could you teach me how to solve this problem? I tried many ways but still didn't get it right.

Comment: this code: myPb.source = myLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, imageLoad); is a bit confused. Want you bind a listener definition with source property of your "myLoader" object?

Answer (score 0):

contentLoaderInfo is a property of the Loader class, not URLLoader.  Also, you can't pass the Loader itself to addChild-- you need to add the content that was loaded. Finally, addEventListener doesn't return anything, so myPb is a meaningless variable.  So, your code should look something like:

```
var myLoader:Loader = new Loader();

btn_Img.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, uploadPic);

function uploadPic(event:MouseEvent):void{
    myLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, imageLoad);
    myLoader.load(new URLRequest("myImage.png"));
}


function imageLoad(event:Event):void{
    var loaded_image = BitMap(myLoader.content);  // or whatever type the load is
    addChild(loaded_image);
}
```

Note that you're not checking for errors on the load, which you may want to add in as well.

See adobe help for [Loader](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Loader.html) and [LoaderInfo](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/LoaderInfo.html) for more details.